# Window function compatibility in Standard SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm exploring the possibility of migrating database code from SQL Server 2012. Existing code relies on support for window functions (WF) introduced in SQL Server 2012, so I would like to find out more about how WF are implemented across different SQL DBMS.

Namely, I'm interested in the extent of WF support in Standard SQL (are OVER(), ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), PARTITION BY, LAG(), LEAD() etc supported? are all/some/none of these Standard?)

Syntax aside, are there any significant differences in how WF are implemented across different on-prem RDBMS? Are there any considerations to be had for cloud-based databases?

We can create a table using

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_T(Employee_Id varchar(50), Employee_name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT EMPLOYEE_T 
  VALUES ('123-44-345','Jim Jason')
    ,('454-56-768','Robert Lewis')
```

The following SQL Server (2012 v11.0.6615.2) command:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(Employee_ID, '-', '') 
, COUNT(*) OVER()
, AVG(CAST(REPLACE(Employee_ID, '-', '') as numeric)) OVER()
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM EMPLOYEE_T
```

returns

```
| (no name) | (no name) | (no name) | (no name) | (no name) |<br>
|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|<br>
|  12344345 |     2     |  28900556 |     1     |     1     |<br>
|  45456768 |     2     |  28900556 |     2     |     1     |<br>
```

The following works in my Teradata Web sandbox:

```
SELECT OREPLACE(Employee_ID, '-', '') 
, COUNT(*) OVER()
, AVG(CAST(OREPLACE(Employee_ID, '-', '') as int)) OVER()
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM EMPLOYEE_T
```

and returns

```
| (no name) | (no name) | (no name)   | (no name) | (no name) |<br>
|:---------:|:---------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:---------:|<br>
|  12344345 |     2     |  28900556.5 |     1     |     1     |<br>
|  45456768 |     2     |  28900556.5 |     2     |     1     |<br>
```

given the identical results it looks to me like there is indeed a

Aside from difference in defaults and data type handling, are there any significant differences in WF functionality across RDBMS other than SQL Server? Perhaps there are some implementation aspects which are worth considering when porting functionality?

Additionally, are these supported in MySQL and postgreSQL? What about contemporary RDBMS such as Azure SQL DWH or Snowflake?

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-02/standard-sql-features-where-postgresql-beats-its-competitors

Comment: Actually SQL Server was very late to to implement window functions (only MySQL was even later...) Nearly all others have supported them for quite a while.

Comment: Note that `row_number()` **without**  a proper `ORDER BY` doesn't really make sense. The SQL Standard allows for `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` btw.

Comment: At least in Teradata `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is useless and returns the same as `ORDER BY NULL`, but it's not a repeatable result. There's one possible issue, in your COUNT example Teradata needs the `rows unbounded preceding`, without it's returning a *group count* (due to historical reasons, TD implemented similar functions 20 years ago)

Comment: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html

Answer (score 3):

Window functions are pretty standard.

One difference in SQL Server is the `RANGE` window frame specification.  This supports only very limited functionality.

Another potential difference is the `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`.  I do not know if all databases support subqueries there.  Most can just handle a constant.  SQL Server doesn't allow constants for sorts, even in window functions.

Teradata can be rather picky about the window frame specification -- requiring it where most other databases do not.  I find that rather clumsy, but others may appreciate the explicit verbosity.

The other major difference is which functions are supported.  The ones you mention, though, are almost always supported if any are supported (SQL Server 2005 and 2008 were exceptions in supporting the ranking functions but not `LAG()` or `LEAD()`).

Comment: Why do you consider `RANGE` limited functionality in SQL Server?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . It does not support intervals, for instance.